# Solarized theme for multiple windows on terminator not working

Tags: ubuntu, terminal, terminator

I am using ubuntu 12.04 LTS with terminator and zsh

i tried to change the theme of the terminator using  https://github.com/ghuntley/terminator-solarized/blob/master/README.md

i have successfully changed the theme of the termninator but when i split the window the splited window is in the old theme instead of new theme

this is how it looks[image]

What is wrong in it

Answer (score 0):

One way to preserve the profile on splits would be to put under

```
[profiles]
  [[default]]
```

the code corresponding to the profile that you want.

For example, if you want `solarized-light` it should look like this:

```
[profiles]
  [[default]]
    palette = "#073642:#dc322f:#859900:#b58900:#268bd2:#d33682:#2aa198:#eee8d5:#002b36:#cb4b16:#586e75:#657b83:#839496:#6c71c4:#93a1a1:#fdf6e3"
    background_color = "#eee8d5"
    foreground_color = "#002b36"
    cursor_color = "#002b36"
```